# How would you tail call optimize this Clojure function that builds a tree?

Tags: clojure, tail-recursion

I have some maps

```
(def m1 [{:a 1, :b 2, :c 0}
         {:a 1, :b 3, :c 0}
         {:a 1, :b 0, :c 2}
         {:a 1, :b 3, :c 1}
         {:a 1, :b 0, :c 3}])
```

which I can recursively group with this function

```
(defn group [ks coll]
  (if (empty? ks) coll
      (let [gs (group-by #(select-keys % [(first ks)]) coll)]
        (map (fn [[k v]] {k (group (rest ks) v)}) (dissoc gs {})))))
```

to produce the expected result:

```
(group [:a :b :c] m1)
```

=>

```
({{:a 1} ({{:b 2} ({{:c 0} [{:a 1, :b 2, :c 0}]})}
          {{:b 3} ({{:c 0} [{:a 1, :b 3, :c 0}]}
                   {{:c 1} [{:a 1, :b 3, :c 1}]})}
          {{:b 0} ({{:c 2} [{:a 1, :b 0, :c 2}]}
                   {{:c 3} [{:a 1, :b 0, :c 3}]})})})
```

How could you rewrite a function like this that has `map` in the last position as it needs to follow multiple paths, to be tail call optimized using `recur`?

Comment: Why do you want it to be tail recursive? It's perfectly fine as is. Lazy is usually better than tail recursive anyway.

Comment: Hi - I am just interested in the practicalities of how to use a stack to maintain & pass all the state in a tree, especially with the additional state of the grouping keys.You're right though; the above function works fine even when you crank up the number of nodes and levels in the tree.

Comment: Also interested in how to replace map with recur. Can't see how to go about that

Comment: Is the expected result you provided correct? Running your example code does not give the provided result. For example, there are no `c` maps with `1` or `3` under `{:b 2}`.

Comment: @Judep here's a blog post on tail-recursive tree traversal: http://lambda-startup.com/traversing-trees-tail-recursively/

Comment: @ToniVanhala The output was not correct. Copy & paste error. Fixed. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original algorithm requires that the current siblings of the node are preserved as context when recurring, so that we can return to processing those siblings after recurring to the bottom. With a slight modification, we can build a full path to one node at a time, depth-first, disregarding the relationships of nodes. This allows more simple tail-call recursion.

```
(defn group [ks coll]
  (group-recur ks coll ks [] {}))

(defn- group-recur [ks coll recur-keys path acc]
  (if (empty? coll)
    acc
    (if (empty? recur-keys)
      (recur ks (rest coll) ks [] (assoc-in acc path (first coll)))
      (let [node (first coll)
            rk   (first recur-keys)
            k    (select-keys node [rk])
            p    (conj path k)]
        (recur ks coll (rest recur-keys) p acc)))))
```

Here's an [online Repl](https://repl.it/JOBH/11) to try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out to be surprisingly complex.  I managed to implement something like the above using `loop/recur`, but I had to introduce a bunch of helper functions to keep it somewhat readable:

```
(defn group-recur [ks coll]
  (let [split-map (fn [m]
                    (->> m
                         (into [])
                         (map (partial apply hash-map))))
        dissoc-non-map (fn [m k]
                         (let [l (drop-last k)]
                           (if-not (map? (get-in m k))
                             (if (empty? l)
                               (dissoc m (last k))
                               (update-in m l dissoc (last k)))
                             m)))
        updater (fn [r k v]
                  (let [s (split-map k)]
                    (-> r
                        (dissoc-non-map (drop-last s))
                        (assoc-in s v))))]
  (loop [k ks
         h []
         r {}]
    (if (not-empty k)
      (let [all (conj h (first k))
            grouped (dissoc (group-by #(select-keys % all) coll) {})]
        (->> grouped
             (reduce-kv updater r)
             (recur (rest k)
                    all)))
      r))))
```

It returns a tree of maps, instead of the collections you used above (which I think is more logical).  The basic premise is that you pass along the result map and update it as you go along.  That's why the `dissoc-non-map` is there, appareantly you can't `assoc-in` in a map if there is already another non-map value present on a higher level.

The loop requires 3 arguments: the list of keys still to process, the key/value pairs that we've currently processed (i.e. the current "position in the tree" if you will) and the resulting map tree.

An alternative (an possibly simpler) implementation could pass along two maps: one with the final result, and one with the intermediate values.  That should eliminate the need for the `dissoc-non-map`.

Comment: Impressive! That is indeed very complex and must have been tricky to get right. Seems to support @amalloy's statement that lazy is usually better; Tail call optimising non-trivial tree recursive functions is .. non-trivial. I agree that the tree of maps is more logical. thank you!